# Xamarin Global Variable in XAML doesn't refresh until later (randomly)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I have 3 global variables in my app.xaml.cs.

```
public static bool _Code { get; set; }
    public static bool _Full { get; set; }
    public static bool _Common { get; set; }
```

I have code in a list that uses these variables to hide/show buttons.

```
<Grid>
                                                <Label
                                                    Padding="4"
                                                    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource ColorWindowBackground}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                    IsVisible="{Binding Path=_Code, Source={x:DynamicResource Application.Current}}"
                                                    Text="{Binding CodeName}"
                                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                                <Label
                                                    Padding="4"
                                                    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource ColorWindowBackground}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                    IsVisible="{Binding Path=_Full, Source={x:DynamicResource Application.Current}}"
                                                    Text="{Binding FullName}"
                                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                                <Label
                                                    Padding="4"
                                                    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource ColorWindowBackground}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                    IsVisible="{Binding Path=_Common, Source={x:DynamicResource Application.Current}}"
                                                    Text="{Binding CommonName}"
                                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                            </Grid>
```

I change these variables on another page.

```
private string selectedDisplayType;
    public string SelectedDisplayType
    {
        get { return selectedDisplayType; }
        set
        {
            if (value != selectedDisplayType)
            {
                SetProperty(ref selectedDisplayType, value);
                if (selectedDisplayType != null)
                {
                    //Update the Ui bools for showing the different types
                    if (SelectedDisplayType == DisplayType.Common.ToString())
                    {
                        SelectorEventObj.Common = true;
                        App._Code = false;
                        App._Common = true;
                        App._Full = false;

                    }
                        
                    else if (SelectedDisplayType == DisplayType.Code.ToString())
                    {
                        SelectorEventObj.Code = true;
                        App._Code = true;
                        App._Common = false;
                        App._Full = false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        SelectorEventObj.Full = true;
                        App._Code = false;
                        App._Common = false;
                        App._Full = true;
                    }
                        

                     
                }
            }
        }
```

However, when I go back to my page. The new button doesn't appear with the different values for the species.
If I click through the app a little, it appears after a random number of moves.
Is there something I need to do to let my model know that the Global Variable has changed?

Comment: Check how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged so that you can alert your view when a property is changed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Comment: In case there are any differences, here is the INotifyPropertyChanged doc that is compatible with Xamarin:  [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface / .NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netstandard-2.1). And here is the general topic for XF: [Xamarin.Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/).